# Select2 Getting value from tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

```
 if ($('#plotOption').val() == "average") {
     alert('av');
 }

 $('#plotOption').select2({
     createSearchChoice: function() {
         return null;
     },
     tags: ["average", "Maximum", "Minimum"]
 });
```

When I select all 3 or two and one of thouse is average it won't show the alert. .val() is for example.
average,Maximum,Minimum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.indexOf()`:

```
if( $('#plotOption').val().indexOf("average") > -1 ) { .....
```